# How can I find out the number of actions I have left to take before ending my turn in civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

In multiplayer where there's a timer I often run out of time while picking a pantheon or something. I was hoping there was some kind of indicator that would let you know how many actions you have to perform before you can end turn. For instance, it tells you that you still have to assign production for several cities, move 5 units and pick a Great Person.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for something different than just the icons that appear on the bottom right side?

Comment: Welcome to Arquade. I can only echo @n_plum's question. In addition, there are no real "actions" as you can always jump to a city and change up production or the like. I think it might be best to narrow down your question. Are you looking for specific actions like unmoved units and pantheon/science/cultural research, etc?